# jQueryRain DateTimePicker Disable all dates, just allows specific selected dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

What I m trying to do is disable all dates and just allow specified dates. But I can not make it work with it's features. Any suggestions.

```
                $('#DateSelector').datetimepicker({
                timepicker:false,
                dayOfWeekStart : 1,
                lang:'en',
                minDate: Date() + 1,
                format:'d/m/Y',
                formatDate:'d/m/Y',
                    onGenerate:function( ct ){
                        jQuery(this).find('.xdsoft_date')
                            .addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
                    }
                });
```

[jQuery Rain DateTime picker](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?lnsG0UbP)